# Visual Studio Cordova ajax call CORS

Tags: c#, ajax, cordova

I use Visual Studio community 2017 with cordova to build an apk of my website.

Everything work except ajax call.

I've got an index.html with :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src * data:;" />
```

Every pages are load through ajax :

```
      $.ajax
       ({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://extern_ip/Site/ajax/" + data + ".php?equipement=" + equipement,
          success: function () {
               alert('ok');
           },
          error: function () {
               alert('non ok');
           },
        });
```

The ajax folder is accessible on my exterior ip.

I've got Whitelist plugin and set this to config.xml :

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
```

However, when I simulate debug on visual studio I've got this error :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://extern_ip/Site/ajax/home.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4400' is therefore not allowed access.
```

And when I generate APK and launch it on my phone, my page just stay white.

What did I miss ? Thank

Edit : I try and ajax call work great on website host by wamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add [Whitelist Plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/) , which will handle the CORS Error . before adding it , trying to removing the configuration related to config file you added

Comment: Whitelist is already install by default. Must I reinstalled it ?

Comment: @Hydro in your php reciveing server add this `header("access-control-allow-origin: *");`

Comment: It work ! Thank ! Is it possible to allow only my phone and my local ip?

Comment: @Hydro then you need `authorization` if you want to work with your mobile only , but onto its a whole new concept, try to raise a new question ,so that you would get some intresting ways :) .. dont forget to upvote if it servers your purpose

Comment: Ok and is there a way to deal with htpassword protection ? I try username/password in ajax options but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Hydro in `header` you can set your custom authorization header ex: `my_api_key` and you can check that key in your server so in this waay you can authenticate the request from your mobile or different mobile

Comment: I want to use htaccess and htpasswd because with the right URL I can logging without taping a password. I try to use this ajax ,: $.ajax({
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('myuser:mypswd'));
    },
    url: "https://www.example.org/protected-data.php"
}); But it doesn't work :/

Comment: @Hydro i dont have any PHP knowledge, as this is a basic server side question i have answered it.